# Careers certifications "remove" buttons do nothing when editing categories

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, cv

When adding ones certifications on http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit, there is a <kbd>remove</kbd> button. When I click on this I get a JavaScript alert "Are you sure?"; no matter what I click it returns to an unchanged page.

Regardless of whether this is a browser issue (have only tested it on FF17.0.1), there is also a <kbd>cancel</kbd> button, which seems to make sense to have *instead* of the remove button for **new** entries.

Comment: @ben is uǝq backwards - Thanks. Like the improvement!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed: remove link no longer shows up for new entries.